# Why do I obtain blank response when listing linux users?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to list all the users of my system with "cut" approach but I obtain nothing, any idea?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f 1 > user   

echo $user
```

Comment: You redirect output to a file. Use `cat user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's already mentioned in the comment above the problem is that you redirect your output to the file named `user`.

So, possible solutions are:

1) Check the `user` file's content.

2) Adjust your command to write it's output to the `user` variable:

```
user=`cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f 1`
echo $user
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use the following (note `>>` instead of '>'):

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1 >> /tmp/user
```

Then the output file is created as expected:

```
$ cat /tmp/user
SYSTEM
LocalService
NetworkService
Administrators
TrustedInstaller
Administrator
boinc_master
boinc_project
Guest
HomeGroupUser$
UpdatusUser
```

(Note that you may want to insert `sort` in there)

Comment: Appending instead of overwriting cannot be the answer. If anything, appending is more likely to be wrong (any previous incorrect or duplicate result will pollute and perhaps even corrupt the result).